# Simulate Location with Xcode 11

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

Well, I am trying to activate Location in my iOS Simulator, but I got unaccessible greyed options. Like this:

[image]

I read about Products > Schemes > Run > Options... But there's no options for Location in there. Like this other image:

[image]

Can somebody help me? How can I do this in Xcode 11? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5):

On Xcode 11 and later, you need to go to the Simulator. Open "Features" in the menu, then select "Location".

Answer (score 3):

You just need to go to the simulator open Debug menu -> Location and all set.
[image]

Comment: Thanks! I came from Windows, so I am a Mac Newbie! Thanks man!

Comment: This didn't solve the problem for me, the buttons are still greyed out, even after restarting XCode. Note that I am running my application in React Native from a regular terminal

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set/fake location for simulate with Xcode 11 or later.

- Step 1: Run your project with any simulator model.
- Step 2: On Dock bar, select to this simulator.
- Step 3: On Navigation bar. select "Features -> Location -> Custom Location..."
- Step 4: in "Custom Location" table, you insert Lat-Lng to this table.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Xcode 13**

You can simulate location in either Xcode or Simulator. For a custom location (with custom coordinates), however, you must simulate location in Simulator, not in Xcode because Xcode does not offer this feature. And to do that you must disable location simulation in Xcode (because it will override Simulator if enabled) and enable it exclusively in Simulator.

To do that, in Xcode, go to "Product", "Scheme", "Edit Scheme" and set "Default Location" to none and uncheck "Allow Location Simulation". Then in Simulator, go to "Features", "Location", "Custom Location" and enter in coordinates.